# Invalid characters in HTML preventing my menu from toggling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a button that makes a table and a drop down menu. But the drop down menu doesn't work when it's clicked, like it should. 
I keep receiving this error: 'Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'toggle' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('[object HTMLCollection]') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.' This error occurs near the last line here where I use toggle.
I've checked the HTML generated with JS and it seems fine. I just can't figure out what exactly this error is referring to. I've gone through the code at least a half dozen times and don't see any spaces within the html. This makes me question whether this is where the problem actually is. If anyone has a solution or insight into how to correct this, that would be much appreciated. 
Here is the code:

```
//**HTML**
<div class = 'insertsGrid buttonStyle'>Grid</div>

//**CSS**
.buttonStyle{
    width: 12vh;
    height: 12vh;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: fixed;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 4vh;
    color: #b8860b;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:white;
    user-select: none;
}
 th, td, tr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

//**Javascript**
    const insertsGrid = document.getElementsByClassName('insertsGrid');
   insertsGrid[0].addEventListener('mousedown', createGrid);
let z =0;
function createGrid (){
    z++;
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', true,/*this is the bar */'<div class=bar'+z.toString()+'></div>'+/*this is the menu options that show when bar is clicked */ '<div class =dropDownContent'+z.toString()+'><div class =dropDownContentX'+z.toString()+'><p>Add Row</p><p class=addColumn'+z.toString()+'>Add Column</p></div></div>'+/*this is the table */ '<table><tr><td>Head1</td><td>Head2</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table><br>');
    let bar =   document.getElementsByClassName('bar'+z.toString());
    let dropDownContent = document.getElementsByClassName('dropDownContent'+z.toString());
    let dropDownContentX = document.getElementsByClassName('dropDownContentX'+z.toString());
    let addColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('addColumn'+z.toString());
    //dom css for the html created in the dom
    bar[0].style.width = '10%';
    bar[0].style.height = '1%';
    bar[0].style.border = '1px solid black';
    bar[0].style.cursor = 'pointer';
    bar[0].style.marginBottom = '50px';

    dropDownContent[0].style.display = 'none';
    dropDownContentX[0].style.display = 'inline';
    dropDownContentX[0].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    dropDownContentX[0].style.width = '100%';
    dropDownContentX[0].style.fontSize = '80%';

    //action executed when the nav button is pressed
    bar[0].addEventListener('mousedown' , tog);
function tog (){
    dropDownContent[0].classList.toggle('dropDownContentX');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `dropDownContentX` into the toggle() method. This is a collection of DOM nodes, not a string. The toggle() method expects a CSS class name without spaces. You are passing the wrong data type to this method.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle